# Why no targum on Ezra?

Tags: targumin, ezra-nechemya

Why does the book of Ezra/Nechemia no have Aramaic targum? Divrei Hayamim has targum R Yosef. Daniel is singled out as not having targum in Gemora Megillah because "in it is the end of moshiach". Besides Doniel is largely Aramaic.
But why do Ezra/Nechemia's Hebrew section not have targum?

Comment: Even the Hebrew parts in Sefer Ezra are very Aramaic in nature.

Comment: Actually the Gemara Megillah implies that none of Ketuvim has Targum, because of the problem that a Targum to Daniel would have presented. Accordingly, apparently any Targumim on Ketuvim were unfamiliar to the Gemara, and are probably of later origin. The question would therefore be why people happened to compose Targumim to some books and not others. This seems largely opinion based; we would have to ask each translator why he chose to translate or not translate different books.

Comment: If the name Targum Yonasan found in chumashim is to be taken at face value all of Kesuvim was translated until Doniel at which point he stopped. Rav Yosef who's targum we have to Divrei Hayamim is recorded in gemora as having translated other parts of Scripture as well.

Comment: @mevaqesh Although I just saw Wikipedia say that targum R Yosef is medieval, implying that this is not the Rav Yosef mentioned in Gemora

Comment: @Naf yes as I said, the targumim are probably post Talmudic

Comment: It is well known that the Targum Yonasan to Chumash was not written by Yonasan ben Uziel.